# How to edit 'bit' data type?

Tags: .net, asp.net, database, vb.net

I am coding in Visual Basic. I am using a checkbox control. Now depending on its checked property I need to set/unset a bit column in a SQL Server database. Here's the code:

```vb
Try
    conSQL.Open()

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("update Student set send_mail = " + _
        sendemailCheckBox.Checked.ToString + " where student_id = '" _
        + sidnolabel.Text + "'", conSQL)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Finally
    conSQL.Close()
End Try
```

The `send_mail` attribute is of bit datatype. This code is not working.
How do I go about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
Convert.ToInt16(sendemailCheckBox.Checked)
```

In general, I use `SqlParameters` for this, and you can specify a `SqlDbType.TinyInt`.

[Here](http://www.sharpdeveloper.net/content/archive/2007/05/25/creating-sqlparameters-best-practices.aspx) is an example of using sqlparameter which is better because it avoids SQL injection.

EDIT: I just noticed you were using `bit`, not `tinyint`. not sure if this will work.

Answer (score 52):

my son is enrolled in your school.  His name is:

> Robert'); DROP TABLE STUDENT; --

We call him little Bobby Tables.

---

<sub><sub>Okay, I have been told that this was going to be deleted as [not an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118582/what-is-an-acceptable-answer) and that I needed to fall on the sword or clean up my own mess.  Although I'll keep</sub></sub>
<sup><sup>my rep if it gets deleted I think it is important to point out the vulnerability in the OP's code (may his account rest in peace).  So lemme elaborate...</sup></sup>

Let's actually fix the above name from the XKCD comic to something that would actually work against the concatenated query (assuming OP's boolean issue has been fixed):

> 123; DROP TABLE STUDENT; --

If we add this in the `sidnolabel` text box (or whatever it is; if it is in the viewstate you could change it with a simple tool), the resulting concatenated query is

```sql
update Student   
set send_mail = 1  
where student_id = 123; DROP TABLE STUDENT; --'
```

which will run a bogus query then drop the Student table.

This is the definition of "not good."

What OP should be doing is using a parameterized query.  This prevents injection attacks like this.  Updating OP's code...

```vb
Try
    conSQL.Open()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(
        "update Student " + _ 
        "set send_mail = @sendMail " + _
        "where student_id = @studentId", conSQL)
    cmd.Parameters.Add( _
        "@sendMail", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = _
            sendemailCheckBox.Checked
    cmd.Parameters.Add( _
        "@studentId", SqlDbType.NChar, 25).Value = _
             sidnolabel.Text ' better to keep track of this in the Session!
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Finally
    conSQL.Close()
End Try
```

Which should fix OP's issue **and** prevent sql injection attacks.  Ain't that something?

*Please note, I don't VB, and this is not tested.  Any VB.NET devs who want to edit and fix errors I'll be happy to accept your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain/332367#332367

Comment: Oh, that's why when we tried to add his record to our database we were getting `Unknown table 'STUDENT'`? :D Keep teaching emm... +1.

Comment: @Shef: In OP's case, the table *is* `Student`

Comment: @paulmorriss: Since when?  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/

Answer (score 6):

To answer your question, just assign a Boolean value (i.e. `sendemailCheckBox.Checked`) to the bit column in the database.

To help you out with your SQL injection issues - do not directly write user input into a SQL string.  You must use parameters to ensure that users cannot mess with your database.  Your code should be written like this:

```vb
Using conSQL As New SqlConnection("SomeConnectionString")
   conSQL.Open()
   Using cm as SqlCommand = conSQL.CreateCommand()
      cm.CommandType = CommandType.Text
      cm.CommandText = "UDPATE Student SET send_mail = @send_mail WHERE student_id = @student_id"
      cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@send_mail", sendemailCheckBox.Checked)
      cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@student_id", sidnolabel.Text)

      cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
   End Using
End Using
```

Answer (score 5):

First, in the name of everything sacred, at least PARAMETERIZE your SQL code.  Otherwise, you're *asking* for a SQL injection attack.

Second, the "bit" datatype uses 1 for True and 0 for False.  That's what SQL wants to see when you're assigning values.

Answer (score 1):

Well bit data type is equivalent to boolean in C# or Visual Basic, so you can simply assign true or false values to these types and can then update the record in your database.

Comment: this.  Also, evil sql is evil.